# track changes in active directory

Tags: events, active-directory, event-sourcing, active-directory-group

I was thinking to create an application (in C/C++ or C# - I am not sure yet) which has to track some changes that  took place only for the user accounts from an Organization Unit (for example: a user account which is a member of "A" OU has been deleted). I have read something about: subscribing to events in event log but it seems that in this case I will receive informations about every user account which has been deleted for example. Using this method it seems that I will have to check if that user is part of my OU.

Another method that I have in mind involves the using of "Polling for changes using DirSync". It seems that this technique uses a search filter but neither in this case I can't reveice changes notifications only for the users from a specific OU. So , I was thinking to create some custom searching filters for a specific type of users (for example: disabled user accounts) but even so, I will have to check the provenience of a user at a specific OU. (inefficient, in my opinion)

Now, here comes the real questions:

How can I track changes in A.D only for a certain group of user accounts? And what would you recommend me to use in this case?

**[Edit 1]**

I know that I can use `USNChanged` attribute but, wouldn't be that inefficient if I am planning to work with deleted objects and if I am tracking just some certain changes that took place in an OU?